# Does building a module using Stack make it available globally?

Tags: haskell, build, module, haskell-stack

I have started using Haskell Stack, and don't have much knowledge about it.

I'm working on two projects concurrently, both of which are GIT/Cabal/Stack setup.
Let's say, `mig` and `che`.
Now the problem is that one of these projects depends on the other.
I'm not sure whether or not it is possible to just add `mig` to the `stack.yaml` of `che`, even after having built it using `stack build`, since GHCi (`stack ghci`) doesn't permit `import Mig.Example`, raising an error.

Is this even a valid problem? What should I do? Can this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stack documentation section on [multi-package projects](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#multi-package-projects) has a little bit about this, but unfortunately chooses to show an example using two off-the-shelf packages which makes things confusing.

The general idea is to put your `mig` and `che` project directories under a common project directory, and then put a single `stack.yaml` file in the common directory that lists `mig` and `che` as the packages to be built (instead of the usual "." package).  The dependency in `che.cabal` on `mig` will then automatically be resolved.

Here's a complete, minimal example.  If you run `stack build` under `multi`, it will build `che`, then `mig`, and `stack exec mig` will run the program.

Also, note that if you put the two existing Stack project directories in place, I believe you should remove their local `stack.yaml` files, and either merge the contents manually into a single `multi/stack.yaml` or run `stack init` in `multi` to generate a fresh `multi/stack.yaml` from the contents of `mig/mig.cabal` and `che/che.cabal`.  There should only be one `stack.yaml` for each collection of projects being built as a unit.

#### multi/stack.yaml

```
resolver: lts-13.26
packages:
- che
- mig
```

#### multi/che/che.cabal

```
name:                che
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
library
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  exposed-modules:     Che
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

#### multi/che/Che.hs

```
module Che where
che :: IO ()
che = putStrLn "Viva la revolution"
```

#### multi/mig/mig.cabal

```
name:                mig
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.10
executable mig
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , che
```

#### multi/mig/Main.hs

```
import Che
main :: IO ()
main = che >> che >> che
```

### Update: Developing `che` on its own

Note that, even if you are also working on developing/building `che` on its own, the above `multi` setup would be the recommended way of setting up the `mig` project.  In particular, if you wanted to build `che` only without rebuilding `mig` (e.g., if you know `mig` is going to be broken while you're working on `che`), you could use the command `stack build che` instead of `stack build`.

If you want to be able to continue developing `che` without interfering with the version of `che` being used by `mig`, then the simplest thing to do is to `git clone` a new repository with working directory, and you can have a copy of "bleeding edge" `che` (with its own separate single-package `stack.yaml`) that you can develop and build independently, and the "stable" `che` on which `mig` depends, which you can `git pull` as required.  It'll be a good idea to leave `stack.yaml` out of Git, or name it `stack.yaml.template` or something and symlink or copy it to `stack.yaml`.

If you truly want to treat your `che` the same way Stack treats Stackage packages and have a single-package project for `mig` that somehow depends on a global `che` package, then you can either: (1) start uploading `che` to Stackage and treat it literally like any other Stackage package; or (2) add an `extra_deps` to the `stack.yaml` file for `mig` that points to a supported global package source.  This can be a [GitHub or other web-accessible repository](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#git-and-mercurial-repos); it can be an ["archive"](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#archives-https-or-local-filepath) (e.g., in `.tar.gz` format created with `git archive`) stored in the local filesystem; or even a Git repository in the local filesystem.  For this last option, absolute paths work fine, but I don't think relatively paths are directly supported.  It would look something like:

```
# in mig's stack.yaml
extra-deps:
- git: /home/me/src/haskell/che
  commit: 8ab4bf759dd934fa31cfca324748af894ca0e224
```

Comment: But what if I want to build `Che` on its own?